# Django i18n explorer verification failed

Tags: django

I am using the below code in my site wide template...

```
{% for lang in languages %}
                        <li>
                            <form name="setLang{{ lang.1}}" action="/i18n/setlang/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                                <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="language" value="{{ lang.0 }}" />
                                <a class='{% if LANGUAGE_CODE == lang.0  %}selected{% endif %}' href="#" onclick="document.setLang{{ lang.1 }}.submit();return false;">{{ lang.0 }}</a>
                            </form>
                       </li>
                      {% endfor %}
```

and in urls.py i have

```
(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'))
```

But on internet explorer i am getting csrf verification failed error... Is the problem about there are two forms on the page?

Comment: Have you put `{% csrf_token %}` in both form?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but you should definitely put a space after  `{{ lang.1` so that it looks like `{{ lang.1 }}`.  It is worth trying that, at least, to see if the semantics is causing a break somewhere.

Comment: End the problem is not with the page having two forms. I have tested with the example on django docs. Internet explorer 8 still gives error 403.

Comment: Yeah I knew as much as that...Could you post the actual error message in the question?  It might help me or someone else solve the problem.

Comment: Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
CSRF cookie not set.
In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:
Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function uses RequestContext for the template, instead of Context. In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL. If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag..

Comment: Can we safely assume you followed all of those steps?  You might want to post the relevant section of your view function, check to ensure you have cookies enabled (I'm sure you do, but still) and check that you have the CsrfViewMiddleware enabled as well.

Comment: The view is generic view. Cookies are enabled. I have the CsrfViewMiddleware enabled.

Comment: Try specifying `return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))` in the view that governs your base template, if you haven't already.

Comment: I have,   -> return render(request, 'works/list.html', {'workList':workList, 'user':request.user } ) <- in my view...

Comment: So the answer to your question was in the error message the whole time?  Add `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` to your tuple?

Comment: Sorry can you explain in detail... Isn't it the same using render(request, 'template_url', {} ) with render_to_response(template_name[, dictionary][, context_instance][, content_type])

Comment: I have used -> return render_to_response('works/list.html', {'workList':workList, 'user':request.user }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))   -> with no luck

Comment: Sorry i was totaly wrong i have checked again the internet options of  explorer and the security was on the high option that blocks the cookie but now there is an other question. So the browser with the high security setting can not change the language...  Is there smt we can do?

Comment: If cookies are required, then any situation that blocks cookies is going to be a problem for you.  Anyone browsing with cookie-blocking options should already be aware of this, but you can do a simple cookie test and at least warn people to turn their cookies off if they want to be able to see multiple languages.  That being said, a guru might know another way to do internationalization that isn't affected by cookies at all, but I am not that guru.